# When opening a pinned program on the taskbar in Windows 8, it starts it on a new location

Tags: windows, taskbar

I have several pinned programs on my taskbar in Windows 8 such as Chrome, IE, and even the Documents folder. When I start any of them, they open on the same location where the program is pinned. The icon just gets "alive" so that I can recognize that the program is running.

However, I pinned Eclipse there too. But when i start Eclipse, the application appears at the end of the taskbar line. Note that the pinned Eclipse icon stays on the taskbar list. So when running Eclipse it takes two positions on the taskbar. How can I make it behave like all other programs?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. The answer is that Eclipse assigns a different application user model ID to the running window, so the pinned icon and the running window do not match. Fix the installer so it sets the correct application user model ID on the Start menu shortcut, and fix the program so it assigns a consistent application user model ID to its windows so they can be matched up with the shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed this too and the solution in my case was to unpin the "old" icon and pin the "new" that appeared after starting Eclipse, this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it had worked once, but after the second launch it behaves the same. However, I am on the right way to fix it. But I do not know who is the bastard who voted down my question? It seems that the guy has a miserable life and here on this site is his way to show it...

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why the question was down voted, I see no reason for it.